# Why we need implement Serializable for classes put in server when create a java web

Tags: java, java-web-start, serializable

I am learning a java web and my teacher makes me must implement `Serializable` for classes put on the server. Why we must do it. Because when I do not implement `Serializable` my server still active. So, who can answer me that Why I have to implement `Serializable` class for classes put on the server-side

Comment: There are many reasons that you might want a class to implement the Serializable interface, the most obvious of which being that you expect to want to serialize that object.  Classes don't generally need to implement Serializable to be put on a server, so why your teacher requires you to do this is a mystery.  I'd suggest that you ask your teacher why they require this.

Comment: Some classes need to be serializable.  For instance, objects that you add to a session often need to be serialized.  But yea.  Ask your teacher to explain.  (That's what they are paid to do ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume we are talking about web apps built on [Jakarta Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Servlet) technology.

Your web app takes up memory on the [web container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) at runtime. The more simultaneous users, the more memory is taken. To alleviate pressure on memory, some web containers invoke a feature whereby the less-active user sessions are written out to disk.

Also, some web containers do this when shutting down. Current sessions still running at shutdown are saved to disk, and automatically reconstituted when the server launches again.

Yet another scenario is [load-balancing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) where multiple web containers working in tandem may relocate some sessions from any over-burdened server to any underutilized server. This transfer occurs on-the-fly during runtime.

In all these cases, the objects of your web app classes must support `Serializable` so that they may be written to storage or communicated over the local network.

In some complicated apps, making all your objects serializable may not be feasible. In that case you may choose to disable those three features I discussed above. Then you would make sure to run your web app on a deployment server that has more than enough cores and more than enough memory to handle the peak number of users your web app will encounter.